# JavaFX FXMLLoader Exception in cmd

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, jar

I'm working on a mp3 player which is using a JavaFX UI. When I start the application in NetBeans, it works fine. But when I create an executable jar with ***Clean and Build*** and start it with the cmd, I get an exception where the FXMLLoader loads the fxml file.

There must be a problem with the paths, right?

**First Project Structure**

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tiy8G.png)

I created a second application and stored everything in one folder. Created an executable jar and it worked fine.

**Second Project Structure**

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vthYM.png)

**Source Code (First)**

```
package jornsfx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JornsFX extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)throws Exception{
        stage.setResizable(false);
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/jornsFX.fxml")); 
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("JornsFX");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    } 
}
```

**Exception (First)**

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
        at jornsfx.JornsFX.start(JornsFX.java:14)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application jornsfx.JornsFX
```

Comment: Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/jornsFX.fxml")

try to add the absolute path

Comment: I solved it. Case sensitive! I renamed everything to lower case.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you for certain, but it looks like

```
getClass().getResource("/views/jornsFX.fxml")
```

in your `start()` method is `null`. The exception suggests it and also the file is named `/views/JornsFX.fxml` in the screenshot.

Comment: Yes, that was the solution. Now it works fine. I totally forgot that Windows filepaths are case sensitive. Thank you :)

Comment: Actually, Windows filepaths do work case insensitive most of the time (at least on NTFS). The JVM enforces case sensitivity in order to have the same behavior on all systems.